# Pass a return value from a method,which is a json array, to android asynctask, doInBackground method as an argument

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, android-json

The JSON array to be passed to the doInBackground is the return value of the following method.

```
   public JSONArray json_encode(){

      String[] log_data;
      log_data= this.credentials();
      JSONObject  json_var=new JSONObject();

       try{
        json_var.put("username" ,log_data[0] );
        json_var.put("password" ,log_data[1] );
         }
        catch(JSONException e){
          e.printStackTrace();


         }

    JSONArray json_array=new JSONArray();
    json_array.put(json_var);



    return json_array;
  }
```

I need to pass the return JSON array to doInBackground method as an argument. How to do it? Both methods are in different class and the method's return value to be passed (JSON Array) is in the first class (main_activity),the second class is aysnctask class ( class background_thread extends AsyncTask  ) , i need to pass the return array to doInBackground method of second class.

Comment: call this function inside doInBackground()

Comment: there is not enough information to help you... If I have to guess you have this method inside a class and the AsyncTask inside another, and you can't access it from there, is it right?

Comment: how about  `private class Someclass extends AsyncTask<JSONArray , Something, Something>` and just `new Someclass().execute(the_array);`?

Comment: Both are in different classes and i can not extend asynctask from main_activity ( first class ) , i can only create an instance of asynctask in main_activity , but i can only pass data as an argument to doInBackground method in the instance . so how can i pass the return value of json_encode() method's return value( JSON Array) to the doInBackground ? Can u help please.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you just want that value in your doInBackground() :-

```
public class yourActivity extends Activity {
  ...
   JSONArray mJsonArray;
  ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ... 
    mJsonArray = json_encode();

    new yourAsyncTask().execute();
    }

       private class yourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

          //Now you can use mJsonArray here as it is an inner class 

          return null;
       }

    }
 }
```